# How to convert a string to a float?

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I'm currently working on a program in Python and I need to figure out how to convert a string value to a float value.

The program will ask the user to enter a number, and uses a loop to continue asking for more numbers. The user must enter 0 to stop the loop (at which point, the program will give the user the average of all the numbers they entered).

What I want to do is allow the user to enter the word 'stop' instead of 0 to stop the loop. I've tried making a variable for stop = 0, but this causes the program to give me the following error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'stop'
```

So how do I make it so that 'stop' can be something the user can enter to stop the loop? Please let me know what I can do to convert the string to float. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Here is some of my code:

```
count = 0
total = 0
number = float(input("Enter a number (0, or the word 'stop', to stop): "))

while (number != 0):
    total += number
    count += 1
    print("Your average so far is: " , total / count)
    number = float(input("Enter a number (0, or the word 'stop', to stop): "))

if (number == 0):
    if (count == 0):
        print("")
        print("Total: 0")
        print("Count: 0")
        print("Average: 0")
        print("")
        print("Your average is equal to 0. Cool! ")

    else:
        print("")
        print("Total: " , "%.0f" % total)
        print("Count: " , count)
        print("Average: " , total / count)
```

Please let me know what I should do. Thanks.

Comment: Please do *not* use all-caps or pleas for help in your titles.

Answer (score 4):

I'd check the input to see if it equals stop first and if it doesn't I'd try to convert it to float.

```
if input == "stop":
    stop()
else:
    value = float(input)
```

Looking at your code sample I'd do something like this:

```
userinput = input("Enter a number (0, or the word 'stop', to stop): ")

while (userinput != "stop"):
    total += float(userinput) #This is not very faulttolerant.
    ...
```

Comment: You beat me to the punch.

Comment: This code didn't work for me... still not clear. Please try to explain further. How can I convert "stop" to a float? Thanks.

Comment: @user3002784, you can't actually convert because it isn't a freaking number. Then, your only options are to validate the string with generict input (strings and check if its stop) and then, it isn't that word, you will convert the number. Note: it would be better to check if its a number using regular expression.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Can you please give me an example of how that would work? Please type out a sample code for me. Thanks.

Comment: @user3002784 my code-example is more pseudocode than what you should actually write. Since you haven't posted any code I can't say exactly how you should do it. My whole point was to first check if the input equals "stop" and if it doesn't then we assume that it is a number. But in real life never trust a user!

Comment: @Daniel Figuerora I tried using your code to check whether the input equals stop, but I got the same error message because of it. I have posted some of my code in the edit, please look at that and let me know what I should do. Thanks.

Comment: @user3002784, I still can't see any part of your code. Are you sure you edited and posted it there?

Comment: @user3002784 The above is the minimal change you could do, but Kyllopardiuns answer is better, since it handles errors, like if the `user` tries to input `"slartibartfast"`. Which surely isn't a number. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could tell the user to enter an illegal value - like maybe your program has no use for negative numbers.

Better, would be to test if the string you've just read from sys.stdin.readline() is "stop" before converting to float.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Maybe you could explain further? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert the string to a float. From what you've said it appears that entering 0 already stops the loop, so all you need to do is edit you're currently existing condition check, replacing 0 with "stop".

Comment: Because your number variable is always converting the input to a float. You could remove this and then check if the input is a float at your first if statement. Then add an elif to check if the value is "stop".

Comment: Well, I need them to be converted to float in order to satisfy the '+=' operations in the while loop.

Comment: Ok, so also try adding while(isinstance (number, float) and number != 0)

Answer (score 1):

Note a few things: if the input is stop it will stop the loop, if it's not a valid number, it will just inform the user that the input were invalid.

```
while (number != 0):
    total += number
    count += 1
    print("Your average so far is: " , total / count)
    user_input = input("Enter a number (0, or the word 'stop', to stop): ")
    try:
        if str(user_input) == "stop":
            number = 0
            break
        else:
            number = float(user_input)
    except ValueError:
            print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
```

**PS:** note that keeped your code "as is" mostly, but you should be aware to not use explicit counters in python search for **enumerate**...

Comment: I get an error message that says "break is outside loop." Does this code need to be put into the while loop or something?

Comment: Where exactly should it go? I ask because I need to have the variable be already converted into float in order to wok with the '+=' operations. Should I put it before these?

Comment: I edited my post, but keep in mind that you will still have problems if the user first attempt is a **"stop"**. You should take care of theses things based on the code above as an example.

Tips: do a while:True, and remove the if(number=0) , use enumarate

Comment: Thanks, this helped so much! Do you know if it would be possible to have the user be able to enter 'stop' at the first attempt?